# filter a json object and loop results grep

Tags: javascript, jquery, grep

I have the following code but I know that there must be a more efficient way to get to my end results.  I need a comma separated string but when I try to use .toString I know that I'm not using it in the right place.  I've included the code that I am currently using

```
function load_data() {
    var response = [
        {"email": "a@123.com","pmid": ["a22222", "a444444", "a555555", "a7777777", "a8888888"]},
        {"email": "b@123.com", "pmid": ["b22222", "b444444", "b555555", "b7777777", "b8888888"]},
        {"email": "c@123.com", "pmid": ["c22222", "c444444", "c555555", "c7777777", "c8888888"]},
        {"email": "d@123.com", "pmid": ["d22222", "d444444", "d555555", "d7777777", "d8888888"]}
    ];

    var singleEmail = $.grep(response, function (element, index) {
        return element.email == 'a@123.com';
    });
    var obj = singleEmail[0];
    var pmid = obj.pmid;
    var pmidList = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < pmid.length; i++) {
        pmidList += pmid[i] + ',';
    }

    alert(pmidList);
}
```

Also is using grep any more efficient than just looping?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery is never more efficient. JS has many useful methods these days. Check MDN for browser support though.

Find the right element:

```
// modern
const element = response.find((el) => el.email == 'a@123.com');
// compatible
var element = response.find(function(el) {
  return el.email == 'a@123.com';
});
```

Stringify the array:

```
const pmidList = element.pmid.join(',');
// or var for compatibility
```

`pmidList` won't have a trailing `,` like your code, but I'm guessing that's good.

References & support:

- [`const` vs `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)
- [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [`array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) vs [`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (grep)

Comment: ok- what am I doing wrong?  I'm using IE11 to debug and the const wont load and when I use the compatible it say object does not support find .  Do I need to add a reference to something?

Comment: but both work in FireFox and Chrome-- is there work around code to use if the browser is IE?

Comment: @user1314159, scroll all the way down to the bottom of the linked docs for array.find and you will see it is not supported by IE.  Look at the linked array.filter docs though.  That is supported by IE.

Comment: Just use 'filter' in place of 'find'.  Note: using your example data you would get an array with a single element from 'filter' (similar to grep).